# Global variables in Unity (changing font size, colour, across all scenes)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, global-variables

I am trying to build an app in Unity, and one of the things I would like to do is to be able to change the font size and the colour from a settings Scene. The way I am approaching this is to use a Global variable and try to access and change it from the Settings Scene, then have all the other scenes get their font size from the set variable.

So far, I have built a global variable class (shown below) and am trying to access it on the click of a button in the settings class. I am not sure if this is the best way to go about this problem, nor am I sure how to make make all other scenes take the information from this globals class and update it whenever a new scene loads.

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static int FontSize {
        get{
            return FontSize;
        }
        set{
            FontSize = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this code crashing coz youare recursively calling FontSize within. FontSize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep data between scenes, you can:

- Use PlayerPrefs
- Use DontDestroyOnLoad
- Use GlobalVariables

This video explains deeply how to use each one and explain the pros and cons.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WchH-JCwVI8

However it might be a little bit outdated (2016).

Now: "it is recommended to avoid using DontDestroyOnLoad to persist manager GameObjects that you want to survive across scene loads. Instead, create a manager scene that has all your managers and use SceneManager.LoadScene(, LoadSceneMode.Additive) and SceneManager.UnloadScene to manage your game progress."﻿

Answer (score 0):

If the fontsize wants to be retained even when the app is turned off

You should use PlayerPrefs.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Otherwise DontDestroyOnLoad(this); use this code.